# React i18n translation flashes and reverts to default in razzle - (server side rendering)

Tags: reactjs, translation, server-side-rendering, react-i18next

I have been able to integrate react-i18next into my project, however, when I change the language in Chrome and refresh the application, it does not change the text. It stays as the previous translation. I noticed that in the terminal where I log data, the translations.json files are loaded for the correct language set in the browser. 
[Video demo showing what happens](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ivDl6ikgzIGh2pov8TxR0Nt-0dZt-c3/view).

From a post I made on the github page for react-i18next, the creator indicated that what I might be missing was passing down initial translations and language so client continues where the server stopped.

I will appreciate if I can get some pointers on how to figure this out.

I have recreated a [sample project here](https://github.com/twumm/myapp-razzle-afterjs-i18n).

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was happening was how I was setting the initialI18nStore and initialLanguage on the [window var:code here](https://github.com/twumm/myapp-razzle-afterjs-i18n/blob/master/src/Document.js#L56).

It turns out I could only(from what I currently know) set it by preceding initialI18nStore or initialLanguage with 2 underscores - so

**`window.__initialI18nStore`**

worked but `window.initialI18nStore` did not.

Hopefully it helps someone working on react ssr projects.